# Abstract repository for entity framwork

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I write abstract repository

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Framework.DataLayer
{
    public class Context<T> : IContext<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

        public Context(DbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public bool TryGet(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, out T entity)
        {
            entity = List(predicate).SingleOrDefault();
            return entity != null;
        }

        public T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return List(predicate).Single();
        }

        public List<T> List(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
        {
            IQueryable<T> result = _dbContext.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
            if (predicate != null)
                result = result.Where(predicate);
            return result.ToList();

        }

        public T Add(T t)
        {
            _dbContext.Entry(t).State = EntityState.Added;
            return t;

        }

        public void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            List(predicate).ToList().ForEach(p => { _dbContext.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Deleted; });
        }

        public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }

        public T Update(T t)
        {
            _dbContext.Entry(t).State = EntityState.Modified;
            return t;

        }

    }
}
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Why are you returning anything from `Add` and `Update`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how I feel about abstracting away something that is already quite heavy abstraction layer. What if you want to use `Include` for eager loading? Or `GroupJoin` for `LEFT OUTER JOIN` between unrelated entities? What if you want to select only 2 properties out of 20 in the entity? When just using EF, you could project the to anonymous type and generated SQL would be quite bearable, but you can't do it here...

Comment: Ask yourself: what is the value of this abstraction? Try to be as concrete as possible. You'll notice: there's not a lot there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one, it is not an *abstract* repository, but a *generic* repository. Never mind. As mentioned in a comment, generic repositories are hardly ever helpful and I would never use them. But apart from that, there's a couple of things I can say about this code:

- `TryGet` should be absolutely safe (that's what the "Try" prefix conveys), so use `FirstOrDefault()` and only return an entity if exactly one is fetched.
- I would not return a `List`, but an `IEnumerable`, so you retain deferred execution.
- If the repository is only internally used, e.g. to supply data for services, I would return `IQueryable`, so you can compose queries from different repositories, do projections, includes and everything you can do with `IQueryable` and not with `IEnumerable`.
- As said in another comment, it is not necessary to return anything from `Add` and `Update`, because you always modify a reference type.
- I would prefer method names like `MarkForDelete`, because that's what actually happens.